Maximizer of one variable function
We define the function $s>0\mapsto\frac{s^2}{2}-\frac{s^p}{p}$, $p>2$. This function has a unique maximizer (in $t=1$). Is it true that the function $$g(s)=\frac{h(s)s^2}{2}-\frac{s^p}{p}$$ has a unique maximizer provided that $$0<c_1\le h(s)\le c_2?$$
It is clear that $0$ is a local minimizer for $g$ and that $\lim_{s\to+\infty}g(s)=-\infty$. Then, there exists a maximum. My question: is the critical point is unique with additional assumpion on the function $h$? For instance, I know that $h(s)>0$ and it is increasing with $s>0$. Maybe in general it is false but I don't have a easy example...

What have you tried so far?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you write “unique maximiser (in $t=1$)”, do you mean the maximum is at $s=1$?

The answer is no. Consider, for example,
$$
h(s) = \frac{10102}{10001}-\frac1{10001}e^{-s}(\sin 100s + 100 \cos 100s+10001),
$$
which always lies between $\frac{1}{10001}$ and $\frac{10102}{10001}$ and is increasing for all $s\ge 0$ because $$h’(s) = e^{-s} (1+\sin 100 s)\ge0.$$
Set $p=4$. The plot of the function $g(s)$ for $0\le  s\le 1.2$ looks like:

Clearly there are more than one local maximum.

Thanks for the example
